# Lightswitch deployment issues in IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to deploy my first lightswitch application in IIS 7.5. I am using MSSQL server 2008. I am using visual studio 2012. There is no problem in the local machine. When I try to publish the application,I get the following error:

Error 1 An exception occurred when deploying the database for the application.
An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallProfile.sql'. The SQL error number is 6951 and the SqlException message is: Access denied.

I have given the lightswitchadmin 'dbcreator' & db_owner role.However, I cannot make it work.

After the deployment is aborted with an error message, I see that a folder is created in the website.When I type the address in browser: I get the following messages.
'An error occurred while communicating with the database'.

If I give a refresh, then a 2 textbox appears for username and password. When i type the application administrator username and password, it shows:
'An error occurred while communicating with the database'.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Musfiqur

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user in the connection string you are using to connect to the database with does not have the correct SQL permissions to create the required database objects.